# Excel Allow Users to Edit Ranges : How to change locked cells in a range to unlocked once paasword for the edit range is entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

It is regarding **Allow users to edit range** option.

I have protected excel worksheet in which there are certain areas of the sheet which is set for `allow users to edit range` . Now, is it possible to change `locked` property of those cells in that range to `unlocked` once the password for the edit range is entered.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a macro that will require a password to run.

Then this macro, can go in, 'unprotect' the sheet (with the current sheets password) and remove the locked property of the sheets.

```
Sub PasswordProtectedMacro()
    Dim Password As String
        Do Until Password = "edit"
        Password = InputBox("Please enter password below", "Password", "????")
        If Password = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop


    ActiveSheet.UnProtect Password:="YourPassword", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

"YourPassword" = Original sheet protection password

"Edit" = password required to allow the macro to work as described

These can be the same. just edit to suit your needs etc.

The answer to your question is NO this is just a work around, hope it helps.